# Using Ant to deploy EAR to remote websphere application server

Tags: deployment, ant, websphere

**I want to automatically deploy a EAR file build in our continuous integration server to a websphere application server**. I looked up the Ant task `wsdeploy`, but the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/api/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/WSDeploy.html) really isn't helpful at all. I added this to my ant script:

**WSDeploy Ant task**

```
<classpath>
    <fileset dir="${dir.was.plugins}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</classpath>
<taskdef name="wsdeploy" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WSDeploy" />
<target name="deploy">
    <wsdeploy inputFile="myearfile.ear"
              outputFile="myearfile_fordeployment.ear"
              classpath="${classpath}"
              debug="true"
              ignoreErrors="false"
              noValidate="false"
              trace="true" />
</target>
```

**My Problem**

I don't know how to specify the remote server address and I'd be glad to get some links to tutorials or maybe a working Ant snippet to deploy an EAR to the websphere server.

We already have some SCP and SSHEXEC tasks running for the portlets, and they're calling the *XMLAccess* interface to place and start the portlets. Do I have to adapt that scripts for the EAR too or is that a completely wrong way to automatically deploy an EAR file?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I rewrote my ant script and now there is no ClassNotFoundException anymore. Still, there is an unexpected behavior: The script wants to use a profile I never specified...

Call to Ant:

```
%WAS_HOME%\bin\ws_ant.bat -Duser.install.root="%WAS_HOME%\profiles\EXPECTEDPROFILE" -f buildall.xml "%1"
```

I want to run all this with `EXPECTEDPROFILE`, but the error message that is following suggests that there is another profile `UNEXPECTEDPROFILE` involved.

Output:

```
wasListApps:
  [wsadmin] WASX7023E: Fehler beim Erstellen der "SOAP"-Verbindung zu "MYHOST". Informationen zur Ausnahme: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: ADMC0016E: Das System kann keinen SOAP-Connector erstellen, um die Verbindung zum Host MYHOST an Port MYPORT herzustellen.
  [wsadmin] WASX7213I: Dieser Script-Client ist mit keinem Serverprozess verbunden. Pr?fen Sie, ob in der Protokolldatei /PATH/TO/UNEXPECTEDT/PROFILE/logs\wsadmin.traceout n?here Einzelheiten enthalten sind.
  [wsadmin] WASX8011W: Das AdminTask-Objekt ist nicht verfügbar.
  [wsadmin] WASX7015E: Beim Ausf?hren des Befehls "$AdminApp list" ist eine Ausnahme eingetreten. Informationen zur Ausnahme:
  [wsadmin] com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7206W: Der Application Management Service ist nicht aktiv. Die Befehle f?r die Anwendungsverwaltung k?nnen nicht ausgef?hrt werden.
  [wsadmin] Java Result: 103
```

**UPDATE 1**

**Using wsinstallapp**

After reading [JoseKs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server/3117920#3117920) I tried to use `wsinstallapp` to install my application with this Ant target:

```
<taskdef name="wsInstallApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.InstallApplication" classpath="${dir.was.plugins}/com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar" />

<target name="deploy" depends="EAR">
    <wsInstallApp
        wasHome="${WAS_HOME}"
        ear="MYAPPLICATION.ear"
        options=""
        properties=""
        profile=""
        conntype="SOAP"
        host="${TargetServer}"
        port="${TargetPort}"
        user="${TargetUser}"
        password="${TargetPwd}"
        failonerror="true" />
</target>
```

But this is what I get:

```
deploy:
[wsInstallApp] Anwendung wird installiert [/path/to/MYAPPLICATION.ear]...
  [wsadmin] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main
  [wsadmin]     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:335)
  [wsadmin]     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:91)
  [wsadmin] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main
  [wsadmin]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:496)
  [wsadmin]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:631)
  [wsadmin]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  [wsadmin]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
  [wsadmin]     ... 2 more
```

I don't know why the task is searching for an Eclipse class...

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, actually we're using a mix of Ant (that copies the EAR with a SCP task) and a jython script that runs on the server machines. The jython is loaded by wsadmin and there we install the server-local EAR file on the node/server.

Comment: And you have to manually run the script after the SCP task or is the build server on a machine with WAS? I find it ridiculous that we can't do automated deployment from a build server.

Comment: No, we scp the EAR artifact and the jython script to the WAS server and execute wsadmin from there. In fact, the jython script is based on the examples from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html

Comment: This exception is caused by missing 2 jar files in your classpath. <WAS INSTALL>/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar & <WAS INSTALL>/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the ant task for actually deploying the EAR onto the remote Websphere is `wsInstallApp` as documented [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wsps.602.javadoc.doc/doc/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/InstallApplication.html)

```
<taskdef name="wsInstallApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.InstallApplication"/>




<wsInstallApp
                  wasHome="location of websphere installation"
                  ear="the ear file you wish to install"
                  options="the options to pass to the installation process"
                  properties="java properties file containing attributes to set in the JVM System properties"
                  profile="a script file to be executed before the main command or file"
                  conntype="specifies the type of connection to be used."
                  host="the host to connect to"
                  port="the port on the host to connect to"
                  user="user ID to authenticate with"
        password="password to authenticate with"
        failonerror="true | false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this task. Unfortunatly the documentation is... I have another problem, but I'll add it to my Q instead of posting it here as a comment.

Comment: Though this doesnt explain the eclipse classnotfound - Here is a real-life example: http://www.jroller.com/holy/entry/was_6_0_ant_tasks. This and other URLs suggest the "profile" must be passed in first. http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=32285