# How to enable IBM Websphere Application Management Service?

Tags: configuration, websphere, admin

I try to use the IBM Websphere `$AdminApp` (and the Ant tasks) to install/update an application EAR on a remote server. [You may want to read this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server).

**Manual process**

I open a jython console with this command line:

```
$was61profile1\bin$> wsadmin.bat -lang jython -host MYHOST -port 32092
```

After that I want to list all applications:

```
wsadmin>AdminApp.list()
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminApp list"; exception information:
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7206W: The application management service is not running. Application management commands will not run.
```

I think the message here is clear: *The application management service is not running.*

**How to enable the Application Management Service?**

I did search for documentation on the horrible, horrible IBM website. I also tried to click through the configuration options on the Websphere admin pages. But I can't find anything remotely close to *application management service*. I do that clicking again with english language settings now, but **I'd appreciate if someone can point me to the configuration option or the documentation**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crap, I was connected to the wrong port. If you want to use `AdminApp.list()` you have to connect to the deployment manager (abbreviated as DMGR). I restarted my console with

```
*WAS_HOME*\profiles\was61profile1\bin>wsadmin.bat -lang jython -host MYHOST -port 32003
```

and then I could list installed applications via `AdminApp`.

Make sure you go to the Websphere Administration console web interface and go to *System configuration* -> *Deployment manager* and check the list of Ports on the right hand side of the page. There is a port for `SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS` and that is what you need to use for the console.

Comment: For WebSphere v 7: Server Types > WebSphere application servers > [serverName] > Communications > Ports: SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS http://blogs.adobe.com/livecyclepost/2011/03/determining-the-soap-port-for-your-ibm-websphere-application-server/

Comment: This post solved my problem as well, tried contacting the wrong port.    
Errors:  
WASX8011W: AdminTask object is not available.  
WASX7206W: The application management service is not running. Application management commands will not run.

Use the SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS for port.  
I found mine from:  
${WAS_ROOT}/profiles/{profile}/config/cells/localhost/nodes/localhost/serverindex.xml