# Deploy an ear file to remote WAS 8 using Maven 3

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Is there a way to deploy an ear file to a remote WAS 8 using Maven

I found a WAS 6 plugin but does it work with WAS 8

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server) that does the deployment.

You can call ant tasks with maven.