# Unable to deploy EAR in WebSphere Application Server in Unix with ANT Scripts

Tags: unix, ant, websphere, websphere-7, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy EAR in my WAS 7.0 in Unix Server by means of ANT Scripts but couldn't get it working.It works fine in Windows environment.

A part of ws_ant.xml is as follows,

```
<property name="options" value="-appname CRMWeb -MapModulesToServers {{.* .* WebSphere:cell=Cell01,node=Node01_POR,server=Web_Server1}}" />

<property name="application" value="CRMWeb" />
<property name="conntype" value="SOAP" />
<property name="host" value="172.20.10.10" />
<property name="port" value="20062" />
<property name="profile_root" value="/opt/app/was7/wasprd02/AppServer" />
<property name="webserverName" value="Web_Server1" />
<taskdef name="wsStartApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.StartApplication"/>
<taskdef name="wsStopApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.StopApplication"/>
<taskdef name="wsUninstallApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.UninstallApplication"/>
<taskdef name="wsInstallApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.InstallApplication"/>


<target name="uninstallApp">
<wsUninstallApp
application="${application}"
conntype="${conntype}"
host="${host}"
port="${port}"
user="${userId}"
password="${password}"
failonerror="false"
/>
</target>
```

When I try to install / uninstall the EAR in Unix with above script, there is no effect. Manual deployment from WebSphere console is working fine.

I have referred [Using Ant to deploy EAR to remote websphere application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server) and tried to make some changes but still it is not working.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: No effect = no error messages or output of any kind?

Comment: There are no error messages / output of any kind.Only my terminal console displays message as BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: And you are running the target uninstallApp somewhere? Double-check with debug logging if need be.

Comment: in unix env, look for <WAS_HOME>/logs/wsadmin.traceout file which should log any deployment error message

Comment: Did you ever get this working? It probably has to do with the profile/bin directory being the wrong one...