# war file deployment from remote machine on mobile first server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

Is there any way that I can deploy a .war file from a remote machine by giving the ip address and port number of the ibm mobilefirst server using configure.xml ant script? In the configure.xml script I need to give path of the server directory and many more path specific to server though while deployment of .adapter and .wlapp I am able to do remotely.

Can anyone help me out with this. Configuration of server are : Application server used is WAS v.8.5.5.5, Mobile first server 7, derby database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are slightly confused...
It's like this:

1. There is an application server, in your case WebSphere Liberty profile
2. There is MobileFirst Server and Console, which are a set of .war and .jar files *that are deployed to the application server*
3. There is your project's runtime, which is also a .war, also *deployed to the application server*
4. There are the .wlapp and .adapter artifacts, which are *deployed to the MobileFirst Server* (or rather, its database, via MobileFirst Console)

This explains why you can deploy the .wlapp and .adapter remotely to MobileFirst Server, because it's a server and is supposed to be also accessible via the web (if setup properly).

But the .war file is an artifact that is deployed to the underlying *application server* (WebSphere Liberty) that runs everything, you cannot deploy it remotely - certainly not via MobileFirst Console.

If you want to attempt to remote deploy it via Ant, you can look at this question: [Using Ant to deploy EAR to remote websphere application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server) (same concept).

Comment: thanks @Idan Adar, but I want to do it remotely only. The link which you have shared isn't working for me. Is their any using ant script I can run my targets on another server machine?